# Не могу понять, как вынести определение дружественной функции из шаблонного класса

Tags: c++

Хочу перегрузить оператор - через дружественную функцию.
В файле класса

```
namespace mth
{
    template <typename T>
    class Vector
    {
     //something
     public:
     friend Vector& operator - (const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);
    };

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& operator-(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
{
    assert(v1.length != v2.length && "The array lengths must be equal");

    Vector<T>temp(v1.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++)
        temp.buffer[i] = v1.buffer[i] + v2.buffer[i];

    return temp;
}
}
```

В main подразумевается какое-то такое использование

```
mth::Vector<int> example(2);
    mth::Vector<int> example2(2);

    example[0]=1;
    example[1]=2;

    example2[0]=5;
    example2[1]=8;

    mth::Vector<int> example3(example - example2);
```

Если не использовать минус в main, то все компилится, а если использовать, то пишет

```
LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class mth::Vector<int> & __cdecl mth::operator-(class mth::Vector<int> const &,class mth::Vector<int> const &)" (??Gmth@@YAAAV?$Vector@H@0@ABV10@0@Z) в функции _main.
```

Минимальный компилящийся пример:
main

```
#include "comandSource.h"

int main()
{
    mth::Vector<int> example(2);
    mth::Vector<int> example2(2);

    example[0]=1;
    example[1]=2;

    example2[0]=5;
    example2[1]=8;

    mth::Vector<int> example3(example + example2);
    example3.print();

    return 0;
}
```

comandSource.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

namespace mth
{

    template <typename T>
    class Vector
    {
    private:
        unsigned int length = 0;
        T* buffer = NULL;

    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(const Vector& r);
        Vector(int _length);
        
        ~Vector() { delete[] buffer; }

        void print();

        Vector operator + (const Vector& other);    
        T& operator [] (const int index);
        friend Vector& operator - (const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);
    };

    template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector()
    {
        
        length = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector(int _length)
    {
        length = _length;
        buffer = new T[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector & arg)
    {
        
        length = arg.length;
        buffer = new T[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            buffer[i] = arg.buffer[i];
    }

    template<class T> void Vector<T>::print()
    {
        cout << "{ ";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            cout << "'" << buffer[i] << "' ";
        cout << "}";
    }


    template <class T>
    Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator+(const Vector& arg)
    {
        
        if (length != arg.length)
        {
            cout <<"[ERROR] vectors doesn't match by size"<<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        Vector<T>temp(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)        
            temp.buffer[i] = buffer[i] + arg.buffer[i];

        return temp;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int index)
    {
        assert(index > -1 && index < length && "Invalid array index");
        return buffer[index];
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector<T>& operator-(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
    {
        assert(v1.length != v2.length && "The array lengths must be equal");

        Vector<T>temp(v1.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.length; i++)
            temp.buffer[i] = v1.buffer[i] + v2.buffer[i];

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: насколько я понимаю - проблема в namespace - нужно вынести функцию из mth

Comment: Перегруженный через метод класса оператор + отлично работает из mth

Comment: А почему вы возвращаете из оператора ссылку на переменную, находящуюся в стеке?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, на самом деле. Я так понял, не надо так делать?

Comment: приведите минимальный компилируемый пример

Comment: После выхода из функции вектор `temp` удаляется из стека, следовательно, ссылка становится недействительной. Но к вопросу это прямого отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выносите шаблон наружу, а дружественную функцию определяете как `operator-<>`

```
namespace mth
{
    template<typename T> class Vector;
    template<typename T>
    Vector<T> operator-(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);

    template <typename T>
    class Vector
    {
      // ...
      friend Vector<T> operator-<>(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2);
    }
    //...
  template<typename T>
  Vector<T> operator-(const Vector<T>& v1, const Vector<T>& v2)
  {/*...*/}
}
```

*Убрал пока ссылку с возвращаемого типа, эту проблему решите отдельно.*

[cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/8nheh)

---

Второй вариант, о котором сразу почему-то не подумал([напомнил @Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1195007/176064)) — объявить шаблонную дружественную функцию по месту:

```
template <class Y>
friend Vector<Y> operator-(const Vector<Y>& v1, const Vector<Y>& v2);
```

[cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/43jz3)

Comment: Выглядит странно, но оно работает. Спасибо, и не могли бы вы пояснить, почему вынесены вверх эти два объявления?

Comment: И у нас получаются два объявления и одно определение для оператора? Первый раз такое вижу

Comment: friend - это только декларация дружественности к шаблонной функции, которую мы объявляем ранее.

Comment: Вообще, лучше ну её эту дружбу, тем более в шаблонах) С плюсом вот у вас никаких проблем))

Comment: Но мне казалось, что это "не по стилю", типа так делать нехорошо